# How can I hide element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default active">
                <input type="radio" name="payment_options" value=1 autocomplete="off" checked>Cash on Delivery
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default" id="bkash-radio">
                <input type="radio" name="payment_options" value=2 autocomplete="off">bKash
            </label>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="trx_id" id="trx_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Transaction ID"/>
```

**jQuery function:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#bkash-radio", function() {
    console.log('test');
    $("#trx_id").attr("type", "text");
});

$(document).on("blur", "#bkash-radio", function() {
    console.log('test');
    $("#trx_id").attr("type", "hidden");
});
```

I am trying to show the the textbox id=trx_id when the second radio option is selected, but when it is deselected I want the text box to be hidden. How can I do this?

Comment: Your code is already doing that. Isn't it?

Comment: Nope. But Roko's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Target your `[name='payment_options']` radios
2. On `change` event see if  `this.value==="2"`
3. Than manipulate the `prop` *type* respectively

```js
$(document).on("change", "[name='payment_options']", function() {
  $("#trx_id").prop("type", this.value==="2" ? "text" : "hidden");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_options" value=1 autocomplete="off" checked>Cash on Delivery
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" id="bkash-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_options" value=2 autocomplete="off">bKash
  </label>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="trx_id" id="trx_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Transaction ID"/>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Solved my problem.

Comment: @MiniGunnR you're welcome ;)